# Translation X Validation of forms, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

We define the entire laravel framework to work with inter-language translation, setting the default language in the configuration file 
(Config / App.php), 'locale' => 'en', everything works perfectly.
When using the App :: setLocale ('pt-br') method, forms validation messages are not translated in real time, keeping the default application configuration configured.
How can we resovler this problem?

[image: Default locale in config]

[image: Default locale in config load start page]

[image: App online select lang]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my mistake!
I was setting the default language through the view with the methods:

**App :: setLocale**

Then after allocating the method app **() -> setLocale ($ setdeflang);** In the controller, everything is working.